# Rails testing with Watir. How do I load my test db with the fixtures from /test/fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir, fixtures

I'm trying to test my Rails App with test fixtures using Watir. The watir tests work but I can't seem to load my test db with the fixtures from /test/fixtures.

I tried using rake tasks with RAILS_ENV=test but only managed to load the fixtures from /db/fixtures/

Comment: if you found a way to do this, do you still need help?  If not you might want to put your findings into an 'answer' or just delete the question, rather than leave it here looking unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this using rake tasks.

```
namespace :watir do
  desc "Initiate the db for watir tests" 
  task :db_reset do
    if (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "test")
      Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].invoke
      Rake::Task["db:test:load"].invoke
      Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
      Rake::Task["db:fixtures:load"].invoke("FIXTURES=x,y,z,....") #x,y,z are the name of the fixtures in test/fixtures/*
    else
      puts "Must be executed with test flag ('RAILS_ENV=test')"
    end
  end
end
```

To run it I do `rake watir:db_reset`

Now I can run the watir tests on the test fixtures

Comment: #where x,y,z are the name of the fixtures in test/fixtures/*